# MS Sql server 2012 : Alter table add column time and disk space for a table with 30 million records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, alter-table

I am trying to add a new column for a table with 45 columns and close to 30 million records. The new column is of int data type with no default valuable and it can be nullable , below is the query

```
alter table xx add column xx int null
```

I am trying to figure out how much time it make take and what is disk space requirement for logging?

My DB is in Simple recovery mode.

Comment: Do it on a copy/restored version, time it, and scale the metrics up and you have a ballpark (not exact) figure to estimate from.

Comment: I think it should be a metadata only change, so shouldn't be of any concern

Comment: You should create a copy of this database. But I think the change will be instant, since there are not additional constraints.

Comment: Yeah but it is taking 35 minutes now , can we do something to make it fast , any settings from sql side.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah but it is taking 35 minutes now , can we do something to make it fast , any settings from sql side.

Comment: The difficulty here is we don't know whether you're lying to us. *if* the only action you're taking is to add a new nullable column, then it should be metadata only and take milliseconds to complete. So, either you're doing more than just what you've represented or (and you ought to check for these things) the activity is taking a long time because it's actually blocked from even starting due to Schema locks from other ongoing queries.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Why would I lie that I have ongoing production system issue. And No there are no on going queries , I am doing this in the down time and I can see the ldf file size increase right after i fire the query.